# read csv file with a few rows of information

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data csv file with first few rows are storing information.

The format is like this:

```
  info1, aa
  info2, bb
  info3, cc

  col1,  col2, col3
  x1,     y1,    z1
  x2,     y2,    z2
```

If I use `numpy.genfromtxt()`, it will show error due to different columns between first three lines, and the rest.

I can use `numpy.genfromtxt(skip_header=3)` to read the data, and `numpy.genfromtxt(skip_footer= )` to read the information.

I wonder if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: You have a working method with only two lines of code.  What would you consider better?

Comment: if by "better" you mean more dynamically read out different types of rows, then you may open and iterate the CSV and process it line by line, as long as you have fixed patterns to extract, for example, two columns means information, three columns means data.

Comment: How would you want this output to look like? Two arrays? Two dat frames? Everything together in a data frame with `NaN`s filling the missing spaces?

Comment: It just feels like need to open the file twice. I am thinking that read in the file one time, and then do further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need a solution like this and I don't know the number of lines in the header block beforehand, I read only the first column.  Then I look in that column for the blank lines, which tells me where the section boundaries are.  Finally I read the full data by passing the appropriate number of lines to skip and read each time.

If the file is large and I care about efficiency, I `open()` it once and pass that file handle to `genfromtxt()` with the number of lines in each section, which means the whole operation takes just two passes over the file (because the file handle remains open, all we need to do is call `readline()` on it to skip blank lines between sections).